# Single insert/delete takes more than 5 sec on merge filtered table

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge, replication

Environment: MSSQL standard edition – 2008 / Windows server 2008 (64 bit)

I have lots of tables with merge publication (filtered) on windows 2008 server and it takes few seconds to insert/ delete single row on that database.

This is what execution plan shows.
Delete single row: 7 sec. It shows 47 queries.
Insert single row (2 columns): 4 sec. 35 queries.

What I can see it MSmerge_past_partition_mappings and MSmerge_current_partition_mappings table take 15%-30% of cost.

Please help to to resole this issue. I can send more details / execution plan if needed.
Thanks You.

-DishanF-

Comment: I'm trying to understand your problem,but i have little bit doubt.Really you need the insert or delete query or you need the both.Try to reply me as soon as possible.

Comment: no. only prob is both operations takes little bit long time to complete. We have same setup with 32bit/mssql2005/replication without having any issue

Answer (score 0):

### Single Insert using below:

## sample code :

```
INSERT INTO Customers
VALUES
    ('Cust1', 'Smith Company', '123 West 51 st', 'Tampa', 'FL');
```

### Single Insert with Multiple Records using below:

## sample code:

```
INSERT INTO Customers
    (CustID, CustName)
VALUES
    ('Cust1', 'Smith Company'),
    ('Cust2', 'Perform Company'),
    ('Cust3', 'Test Inc');
```

Is this useful for you ?? Reply me as soon as possible

Comment: NO. this is not what I want. I'm having some performance issue.

Comment: hi dishan..can u just brief clarifying it ? when ur performance is lacking in the multiple insert or multiple delete ? which action would be performed ? Tell me ur scenario,I will try to clarify ur issue ..